# How to make order for strings according to some filed

Tags: linux, bash, unix

```
<scene name="scene_1_Overview" title="1 Overview" onstart="" thumburl="panos/1_Overview.tiles/thumb.jpg" lat="" lng="" heading="">
    abc
</scene>

<scene name="scene_1_Overview" title="10 Overview" onstart="" thumburl="panos/1_Overview.tiles/thumb.jpg" lat="" lng="" heading="">
    abc
</scene>

<scene name="scene_10_Room_Balcony_View" title="2 Room Balcony View" onstart="" thumburl="panos/10_Room_Balcony_View.tiles/thumb.jpg" lat="" lng="" heading="">

    abc
    def
</scene>
```

Saying that I have such a XML file as above.
Now I need to make the three elements in order according to the numbers followed by `title=`, which are 1, 10 and 2.

I'm considering using bash script to do this.
I can use things like `awk '{print $3}' test | awk -F "\"" '{print $2}'` to get the three numbers but I don't know how to read multiple lines from each `<scene` to `</scene>`, to make them in order and overwrite them.

Comment: do you want to sort items in ascending order of title value?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest  yeah.

Comment: Doing anything in Bash immediately becomes 10x more complicated when you try to handle multiple lines at once.  It would probably be easier to reformat your file to put one `scene` per line, sort those, and then put your file back in your original format.  But if that is not an option, you may have to try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315889/how-to-sort-with-multiple-lines-in-bash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think doing this in `awk` is not the greatest idea, but I know what it's like being stuck on a box where you lack access to install anything. If you are stuck with it then something like the following awk script should get you in the ballpark.

```
 awk -F"[\" ]" '$0~/title/{title=$6} {scene[title]=scene[title]$0"\n"} END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"; for (title in scene) {print scene[title]}}' inFile
```

Here awk is:

1. Splitting each line by either `"` or  (`-F"[\" ]"`)
2. If the line contains the word `"title"` (`$0~/title/`), then it sets the variable `title` to whatever it finds in field 6 (`title=$6;`) which might change if your "name" contains spaces since we are splitting on that so you might have to monkey with the delimiters.
3. Next it stores the contents of the line, followed by a linefeed, into the array `scenes` at the index set by the number stored in `title` (`{scene[title]=scene[title]$0"\n"}`)
4. Once it's done processing the file it sets the `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` setting to `@ind_num_asc` which tells awk to loop through arrays using the index, while forcing the index to act as a number `(END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"`)
5. Then we loop through the array and print each element (`for (title in scene) {print scene[title]}`)

Minimized a bit:

```
 awk -F"[\" ]" '$0~/title/{t=$6}{s[t]=s[t]$0"\n"}END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";for(t in s)print s[t]}' inFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Using xsltproc

```
$ xsltproc sort.xslt scenes.xml
```

sort.xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:sort select="scene/@title" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Otherwise the following perl one-liner

```
perl -e '
    undef$/;
    print "$_\n" for sort{
        ($a=~/title="(.*?)"/ms)[0] cmp ($b=~/title="(.*?)"/ms)[0]
    }<>=~/<scene[ >].*?<\/scene>/gms
' scenes.xml
```

Comment: Haha, I feel like if you have to split your code into multiple lines to make it readable, maybe the term "one-liner" no longer applies...