# Sorting a file in UNIX

Tags: sorting, unix, ksh

I am trying to sort the rows of a text file in Unix Korn shell.

Sample File:

```
3|"Apple"|"iphoneX"|"This is the latest phone."|"California"
2|"Samsung"|"s9"|"This phone isn't so good.
It hangs for no reason when old."|"Texas"
1|"OnePlus"|"5t"|"This is a good android phone."|"Arizona"
```

Expected O/P:

```
1|"OnePlus"|"5t"|"This is a good android phone."|"Arizona"
2|"Samsung"|"s9"|"This phone isn't so good.
It hangs for no reason when old."|"Texas"
3|"Apple"|"iphoneX"|"This is the latest phone."|"California"
```

I tried this:

```
${FileDir}${INPUT_FILE} |sort -t '|' -k ${SORT_COL_ORD} >>${FileDir}${SORT_OUTPUT_FILE}
```

But it's failing due to a new line feed in row 2. And my O/P is something like this :

```
1|"OnePlus"|"5t"|"This is a good android phone."|"Arizona"
2|"Samsung"|"s9"|"This phone isn't so good.
3|"Apple"|"iphoneX"|"This is the latest phone."|"California"
It hangs for no reason when old."|"Texas"
```

I am passing an arg to sort on col 1 (Ids).What am I missing here?

Comment: `sort` sorts lines.  You're going to need to transform the input so that single logical lines are on a single physical line.  You might do that by replacing any occurrences of backslash with double backslash, any occurrences of newline in a logical line with `\n`, and then sort the data appropriately, and finally undo the transform.  It is at least as much fiddly as difficult.

Comment: if you run a search for 'sort multiple lines' you should get some hits that can help, eg: [How to sort multiple lines in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11315889/7366100) , [Sort text files with multiple lines as a row](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/333961/234539)

Comment: The hard part in this situation is determining which lines need to be combined.  How hard that is to manage depends on how general a solution you need.  What you've got is a version of CSV — character separated values in this context, rather than comma separated values. Are all non-numeric fields quoted?  It looks like it, whether the quotes are necessary or not.  Supposing one of the fields said `It is wonderful except it has no "|" (pipe) character` — how would that be encoded?  At this point, something like Perl with the Text::CSV module(s) starts to be beneficial.  Perl can sort, too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion guys. I am not sure if it's a proper solution but i managed to solve my case here. I replaced the newline with a named string, sorted the files and then replaced with a newline.
awk '{z=gsub("\"","\""); if ( ( z%2) && (nl==0)) { printf $0"WWNewLineWW" ; nl=1} else {print ; nl=0}}'